# How to remove from the list of strings, using regex for all the strings in between 'a' and 'b'?

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I wrote a function that searches for a given text in the file and returns all the lines where this text appeared (in the `new_list`). I would like to delete all the text that's between a character '/* ' and ' */' (including these characters), as these are comments, and are not necessary in the returned list. So now it returns something like:

`new_list = [ '123456_xxxx /* cccccccccccccc */ /\n",  '67890_yyyy /* cccccccccccccc */ /\n", ... ]`

and the goal is:

`new_list = [ '123456_xxxx",  '67890_yyyy", ... ]`

I tried using **re library** and regex **(?<=§).*?(?=;)**

`new_list = re.sub('(?<=/*).*?(?=*/)', '', str(new_list))` but this one gives an error:

`error: nothing to repeat at position 13`

PS I also tried with replace but it only deletes the characters and not everything between them:

`new_list = [s.replace(' /*', ' ') for s in new_list]`

Comment: You have to escape the two asterisks with a backslash like so `\*`.

Comment: It appears you wish to do more than  removing the comments, you wish to also remove any following spaces and then a newline.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

list = [ f'123456_xxxx /* cccccccccccccc */ /\n',  f'67890_yyyy /* cccccccccccccc */ /\n']
newList = []

pattern = f'\/\*.*\*\/'
for str in list:
    newList.append( re.sub(pattern, '', str))
    
print(newList)
```

```
['123456_xxxx  /\n', '67890_yyyy  /\n']
```

if you don't want   and `\n`
change the pattern:

```
pattern = f' \/\*.*\*\/ \/\\n'
```

```
['123456_xxxx', '67890_yyyy']
```

Comment: The second pattern doesn't delete the \n. I tried to add a backslash but it still doesnt work..

Answer (score 1):

Just use `\/\*.*?\*\/` and remember to supply the re.S flag to search across multiple lines.

Both the / and the * are special and need to be prefaced with a backslash () to be taken literally.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.search` with the following regular expression.

```
^(?:(?!\/\*).)+(?<!\s)
```

[Python demo](https://tio.run/##VY1BDsIgEADvvGJ7YhcNqFUPjYaPEI1pSNtDgSw0qa9Hrs55JpO@ZY6hr3VZU@QC7IXIheEJ8nzpr7f7e2@AUTD@AcqAcUEKwdPebJYvtAPazhmnSNMB7aNzmZqQeAkF2evsPzzO2IIjtAfpieOW8EQkav0B)<sup><sub><-</sub></sup><sub>\(ツ)/</sub><sup><sub>-></sub></sup>[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lfUg9X/1)

`(?:(?!\/\*).)` matches a single character in the string (`.`), starting at the beginning of the string (`^`). `(?!\/\*)` is a *negative lookahead* that asserts that the following two characters in the string are not `/*`. In other words any character is matched until and if it is `/` and the next character is `*`. This is called the [tempered greedy token technique](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed).

I've added the *negative lookbehind* `(?<!\s)` to ensure that the match does not end in a whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Using index of strings

**Code**

```
old_list = ['123456_xxxx /* cccccccccccccc */ /\n',  '67890_yyyy /* cccccccccccccc */ /\n']

new_list = []

for i in old_list:
    new_list.append(i[:10])

print(new_list)
```

**Output**

```
['123456_xxx', '67890_yyyy']
```